# Calling method with delay in main thread

Tags: ios

Hello guys I am in need.. Please help me out.
Below is the thread i run in my app which is called every .30delay.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    notification = [[NSNotificationCenter alloc] init];
    notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.30 target:self selector:@selector(notificationTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

});
```

What i want is in method "notificationTimerFired" i am calling one more method and that is to be called say for 5sec interval.. How can i do that.. I tried to adding following code but at the 1st time it called for specified delay but later it calls continually with dispatch_async method is called. Please reply me I am badly in need

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.30 target:self selector:@selector(notificationTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: are you saying that every 0.30 seconds you want notificationTimerFired to then call something 5 seconds later?

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve as the end result (and why??)?

Comment: @D80Buckeye yes i have several methods are called in "notificationTimerFired" and those methods i want to call after particular delay..

Comment: @Wain I have some set of conditions in app by which satisfying i need to call some methods mean while i need to check all conditions for .30delay continuously ..

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I found solution to my problem and it goes as follows

```
//run only once for specified delay        
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        notification = [[NSNotificationCenter alloc] init];
        notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:frequency*60
                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(repeateThreadForSpecificInterval:)
                                                           userInfo:nil
                                                            repeats:YES];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
```

dispatch_once is the key which I was searching for. Any way thanks for your replies..