# NSNotification with delay

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, nsnotificationcenter

How to post `NSNotification` with delay.

One solution that is in my mind :- post notification in `performSelectorAfterDelay` method. Is there any better solution for this.

Is [NSNotificationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationQueue_Class/index.html) can help me to achieve this ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171352/calling-method-with-delay-in-main-thread

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make use of GCD's [`dispatch_after()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) method. In Objective-C, this would look like:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:someNotification];
});
```

**Update: Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)) { 
    NotificationCenter.default.post(someNotification)
}
```

Comment: Right said. We must use GCD in swift rather than performSelector. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSLocalNotification and set a fireDate.
The main difference is that with NSLocalNotification, the user will see the notification when the app is in background ( like it is a RemoteNotification).

It could be useful if you notification is a Reminder or that kind of thing.